# How to catch (and hopefully fix) a GDI resource leak

Tags: c#, user-interface, gdi, resources, memory-leaks

My application logs an exception after running for 6 hours:

OS Version: Microsoft Windows NT 5.1.2600 Service Pack 3 (5.1.2600.196608)

.NET Version: 2.0.50727.3082

SQL Server Version:  9.00.4035.00

SQL Server Level:  SP3

SQL Server Edition:  Standard Edition

Error Message: Parameter is not valid.

Exception type: System.ArgumentException

Source:  System.Drawing

```
Stack Trace: 
at System.Drawing.Graphics.GetHdc()
at System.Windows.Forms.ImageList.GetBitmap(Int32 index)
at System.Windows.Forms.ImageList.ImageCollection.get_Item(Int32 index)
<<< MY code >>>
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant section of your code please.

Comment: The nature of the question is about profiling a large project for GUI resource leaks.  Given a good profiling technique, my code becomes irrelevant.

Comment: To get me started I went ahead and downloaded GDIView.  I guess unmanaged resource tracker is a good place to start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recently I've created a simple class that calls [`GetGuiResources()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683192(VS.85).aspx) function in both the constructor and destructor and reports any differences in GDI object counts. Using it as a scoped object in a few functions helped me plug GDI leaks in the code.

Comment: GDIView basically does the same thing..  Yet there's no code to write.

Answer (score 2):

[GDIView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/gdi_handles.html) worked for me.  It pointed to a Font leak.  I did a search for ToHfont().  The rest is history.

Comment: I wished Nir Sofer would speak up, so I could give him the well-deserved credo.

Comment: Thanks for that! it just helped me solve my GDI handles hitting the 10K limit.